# get editext,spinner and selected date textview tex from listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am working on an application. In which i am creating dynamic layout for user input like(name, age ,date of birth) and i am trying to  create this layout through listview.
I am able to create the layout but when i am trying to getting user input values nothing is appearing and even if user is selecting their date of birth nothing is showing in textview of listview.Even if i am trying to show this layout more than 2 times its not happening.

Please help me .how can i retrieve listview values that user has typed and add the layout more than once.
below is my adapter class:

```
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView,   ViewGroup parent) {

       holder=null;
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_travller,null);

            holder=new ViewHolder();

            holder.passengerType=(TextView) convertView.findViewById        (R.id.Adult_Detail);
            holder.Title=(Spinner) convertView.findViewById (R.id.Adult_Title);
            holder.Adult_firstName=(EditText) convertView.findViewById  (R.id.Adult_FirstName);
            holder.MiddleName=(EditText) convertView.findViewById   (R.id.Adult_Middlename);
            holder.Lastname=(EditText) convertView.findViewById (R.id.Adult_Lastname);
            holder.DOB=(TextView) convertView.findViewById  (R.id.Adult_DOB);
            holder.saveButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById   (R.id.saveButton);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        holder.DOB.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year).append  (month).append(date));
      //  holder.passengerType.setText(Details.get  (position).getPassengerType());
       // holder.Title.setAdapter(holder.spinneradapter.getTitle_adapter    ());

        holder.Adult_firstName.setTag(position);
      /* holder.Adult_firstName.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener()      {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String firstName = holder.Adult_firstName.getText().toString                ();
            Log.i("onclick",firstName);
        }
    });*/

       /* holder.Title.setOnItemClickListener(new   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int   position, long id) {
                holder.spinneradapter.setAdult_Title(position);
            }
        });*/

            holder.DOB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
        DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog=new DatePickerDialog  (context,datepicker,year,month,date);
        datepickerdialog.show();

                }
            });

        holder.saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String firstName = holder.Adult_firstName.getText   ().toString();
                String middleName=holder.MiddleName.getText().toString();
                String lastName= holder.Lastname.getText().toString();
                String spinner_value=holder.Title.getSelectedItem   ().toString();

                passengerDetails.add(new PassengerDetails       (spinner_value,firstName,middleName,lastName,""));

                Log.i("values",""+firstName+middleName+lastName         +spinner_value);
            }
        });




        return convertView;
         }

             private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datepicker=new      DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedyear, int        monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,selectedyear);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,monthOfYear);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DATE,dayOfMonth);
            year=calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            date=calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);


                   }
         };
        public  class ViewHolder{
 //  PassengerDetails spinneradapter;
   TextView passengerType,DOB;
   Spinner Title;
   EditText Adult_firstName,Lastname,MiddleName;
   Button saveButton;

     }
```

and my main class

```
 public class Traveller_Details extends AppCompatActivity {
 Toolbar traveller_toolbar;
Context context=this;
 AlertDialog dialog;
   EditText Adult_EDText,Child_EDText,Mobile_EDText,EmailEDText;
    String Firstname;
   Button call,ConfirmBooking;
   List<String> Child;
    Search_flights search_flights=Search_flights.getSearch_flights();
   int Num_of_Passengers;
    PassengerDetails passeneger;
    ListView Passengers;
   List<String> passengerDetails;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.traveller_details);

               Num_of_Passengers=search_flights.getAdult()+search_flights.getChild()+search_flights.getInfant();

     Passengers=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.Passenger_Detail_List);


    passengerDetails = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        passengerDetails.add("traveller1");

    }
     Passenger_DetailAdapter pdAdapter = new Passenger_DetailAdapter(this,    passengerDetails);

  Passengers.setAdapter(pdAdapter);
```

}

Comment: please add you holder class  and the  Main activity class

Comment: Holder class is needed. Here is an example that may help: 
https://goo.gl/ysaEdb

Comment: please check my edit questio n

Comment: i know how o create custom listview with textview and buttons . but i have Editext , spinner and selectdate  for layout.. i am facing trouble to getting all these values that user has selected